# The json file can not be inserted into a PostgreSQL table

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

```
create table tmpdocs1(title text,abstract text,authors text,biblio text,pmid text);

create table tmpdocs2(title text,abstract text,authors text,biblio text,year text,volume text,issue text,fpage text,page text,pmid text);

COPY tmpdocsX  FROM 'location of said json file'
```

I have used all the delimiters that I could think of and still nothing.
This one of the json file contents.
It has 50000 more.
One of the most problematic things are the " ' " in the text and the " , " .

```json
{"title":"Health inequality in adolescence. Does stratification occur by familial social background, family affluence, or personal social position?","abstract":"Background Two new sets of stratification indicators – family's material affluence and adolescent's personal social position- were compared with traditional indicators of familial social position based on parental occupation and education for their ability to detect health inequality among adolescents. Methods Survey data were collected in the Adolescent Health and Lifestyle Survey in 2003 from nationally representative samples of 12-, 14- and 16-year-old Finns (number of respondents 5394, response rate 71%). Indicators of the familial social position were father's socio-economic status, parents' education, parents' labour market position. Indicators of material affluence were number of cars, vacation travels, and computers in the family, own room and amount of weekly spending money. Adolescent's personal social position was measured as school performance. Measures of health were long-standing illness, overweight, use of mental health services, poor self-rated health and number of weekly health complaints. Ordinal logistic regression analysis was applied to study the associations between stratification indicators and health variables. Results All three groups of indicators of social stratification showed inequality in health, but the strongest associations were observed with the adolescent's personal social position. Health inequality was only partly identifiable by the traditional indicators of familial social position. The direction of the inequality was as expected when using the traditional indicators or personal social position: adolescents from higher social positions were healthier than those from lower positions. The indicators of family's material affluence showed mainly weak or no association with health and some of the indicators were inversely associated, although weakly. Conclusion In addition to traditional indicators describing the socio-structural influences on the distribution of health among adolescents, indicators of family's material affluence should be further developed. Adolescents' personal social position should be included in the studies of health inequalities.","authors":[{"surname":"LK","given_names":"Koivusilta"},{"surname":"AH","given_names":"Rimpelä"},{"surname":"SM","given_names":"Kautiainen"}],"biblio":{"journal":{"title":"BMC Public Health","issn":""},"year":"2006","volume":"6","issue":"","fpage":"110","lpage":"110"},"pmid":"16643660"},
```

Comment: What is the error message you get?

Comment: Note that [COPY](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) works with either binary or text files in a proprietary format or with CSV files. It does not work with JSON files.

Answer (score 2):

COPY supports "text", "CSV", and "binary", none of which directly fit what you want.

Also, your json is not valid, it ends with a dangling comma.

What you can do is load the text to a temp table, then cast it to JSONB and parse it out.

```
create temp table j (j text);
\copy j from json.txt ;
insert into tmpdocs1 select t.* from j, jsonb_populate_record(null::tmpdocs1,substring(j for length(j)-2)::jsonb) t;
```

The `substring` is just to get rid of the trailing space and dangling comma. Presumably you would want to do it somewhat differently in real code.  But since you only showed us one line, I refrained from speculating what the rest would look like.